# Changing SDL TMS Configuration ID mid-use

Tags: cme, web8.5, content-manager, translation-manager

Is it possible to change the SDL TMS Configuration ID for a source publication in Tridion "mid-use"?

So whats the impact of sending a translation job whilst configured to Configuration ID "A", then changing this to Configuration ID "B" (and updating source/target publications).

- Will Translation Manager complain?
- Would the original translation job be lost or corrupted?
- Assuming language pairs haven't changed would there be any impact?

Has anyone any experience of doing this?

Cheers

Comment: I * assuming* that the content would come back in to the publication it went out as (this is in the package sent out) - the items would be checked back in - everything else would then be dependant on setup/code at that point. If you change the parent relationships - etc. - would it matter as you're just re-chcking content in. Now if you check out that content - there's an issue (or if you change the content model for that content etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, and correct me if I am mistaken, Translation service sends and retrieves translation **PER CONFIGURATION**. What it means is that every time service tries to retrieve translation per job, it will get configuration and try to localize components/pages/keywords in publications specified in configuration.

So if you change configuration mid-use, I guess all your unfinished translation jobs will stay stuck, or even worse, can cause components to localize in new publications. I know this is not definite answer, but its somewhat a hint. I know that when we were doing config change, we had to retrieve all ongoing jobs, change configuration, and create new jobs.